# Filter content in view by user field

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I'm having problems filtering a view. This is my case:

When a **user registers** he has to select some **suppliers** of a **list** (This is a term reference as a field of my user).

A user can also create a product. Now I would like to show the products where the suppliers reconcile.

This is an example:

**USER 1** has **suppliers A & B**.
**USER 2** has **supplier A**.
**USER 3** has **supplier B**.

**USER A** can see the products of **USER 2** and **USER 3**.
**USER B** can see products of **USER 1**, but **NOT USER 3**.
**USER C** can see products of **USER 1**, but **NOT USER 2**.

But I'm having trouble making this filter in a view. Could someone help me on my way on how to make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Supplier field lives in the user profile you could make the Product fields dependent on the Supplier field using the **Conditional Fields** module, grant various roles field/taxonomy term access to Product fields using the **Field Permissions** or **Taxonomy Permissions** module, and then create a rule that fires based on Supplier field values that modify user role assignments accordingly

Then you would add *all* Supplier and Product fields to your view, hiding each Product field in the display, and then add a *Global: Custom text* field called "Products" and use replacement patterns to reference each of the hidden fields one after the other. (Make sure the hidden fields appear before the *Global: Custom text* field.) Anything that comes up empty simply won't appear.

If those fields live in a node, that may require a slightly different strategy, but the idea should be more or less the same.